# Using Schema to create indices with the Neo4J Java REST binding

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I am currently using the neo4j java-rest-binding project to try and make the client code the same for embedded and remote databases, which is highly desirable for me.

But I am currently having trouble with the following bit of code when executed on the remote server:

```
protected void createDefaultIndices(GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
    Schema schema = graphDb.schema();
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {
        /* Folder index on path property. */
        schema.indexCreator(DynamicLabel.label(FolderNode.FOLDER_LABEL))
                                        .on(FolderNode.PATH_PROPERTY)
                                        .create();
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        tx.finish();
    }
}
```

When I attempt to execute this, the following exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:      
org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.schema()Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/schema/Schema;
```

Is the schema API implemented for the REST implementation of the GraphDatabaseService?  Or do I need to go about this some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the java-rest-binding project, it seems like the new style of indices and labels are NOT implemented, which is probably why this fails.  Can someone confirm this?

Comment: That seems correct. Many methods have changed definitions since then like find() does not exists anymore, but its findNodesByLabelAndProperties. I am not sure why there is no active development on java-rest-binding  project. Please share if you got any information, or a way to proceed.